# Blackberry webworks : support HTML5

Tags: html, blackberry, audio, stream

please help me.. anyone know? is it my blackberry bold 9700 (5.0.0.469) support HTML5 for audio stream? thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i've tested it with a simple webworks for smartphone application on similar platform, diff phone: BB Curve 9300 (5.0.0.846) and there is NO support for the HTML5 audio tag.

Comment: UPDATE: now with the new webworks, you can use   blackberry.audio.Player("file://blah.mp3").play(); javascript api.. works like a charm!

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 is only supported from 6.0 and up, since they moved to Webkit for the browser.

[BlackBerry provide a library](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Web-Development/Supporting-Gears-using-HTML5-in-BlackBerry-WebWorks-applications/ta-p/557280) to map certain HTML5 calls to Google Gears calls so that they can be supported by 5.0. Unfortunately, this seems to be mostly for the data persistance aspects, and not for anything too fancy.